# How To Get Primary Key From AuditLog Table (Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnEventSaved)

Tags: audit.net

I'm using this code block to save Audit information to a Detail table. During this save, I need to get the PK from the AuditLog table record that was just saved so I can add the Detail record.

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnEventSaved, scope =>
{
   auditService.ConfigureAuditDetail(scope);
});
```

Since I only have scope available I am unable to locate the AuditLog entity except by a lookup against the context. Is this safe or could another record be saved before I get the right PK.

ctx.AuditLog.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().Id;

Is there any way to do this better?

```
    public void ConfigureAuditDetail(AuditScope scope)  
    {
        var efEvent = (scope.Event as AuditEventEntityFramework)?.EntityFrameworkEvent;
        
        List<EventEntryChange> currentChanges = new List<EventEntryChange>();
        var ctx = efEvent.GetDbContext() as DbContext;

       var auditLogId = ctx.AuditLog.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().Id;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map your audit tables like this, so `AuditLog` have a collection of `AuditLogDetails`:

```cs
public class AuditLog
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuditLogDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public string Table { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}

public class AuditLogDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuditLogId { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can specify the mapping and the action for Audit EF like this:

```cs
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
        .UseDbContext<MyContext>()
        .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))
        .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((auditEvent, entry, auditLog) =>
        {
            auditLog.Table = entry.Table;
            auditLog.Action = entry.Action;
            auditLog.Details = entry.ColumnValues.Select(c => new AuditLogDetail()
            {
                Column = c.Key,
                Value = c.Value.ToString()
            }).ToList();
        })
        .IgnoreMatchedProperties());
```

So the audit entities are saved on the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried this out and worked perfectly! I refactored my ConfigureAuditDetail method to take the entry object and return a collection which I loop through and set = to audlitLog.AuditLogDetails

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the actual entity you are saving via Entity Framework, you can extract the Id or Primary Key Value from it directly. I do it using an extension method I wrote:

```
public static object GetPrimaryKeyValue(this EntityEntry entry)
{
    return entry.Metadata
        .FindPrimaryKey().Properties
        .Select(property => entry.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue)
        .FirstOrDefault(value => value != null);
}
```

Comment: Ok yes, I tried just getting the PK from the Entries collection, however, that PK was related to the table under audit which just had data saved against it.  

So to explain better, I have a table called Customers...after that record is saved,  the Audit Core framework saves a new record to a custom table I created called AuditLog. This table simply stores the entity name (Customers), the type of action (Insert/Update), and a few relevant keys.

Comment: After this is complete I call that CreateAuditLogDetail method to save a new record to the child table of AuditLog. It is here where I have to have the PK of that new record that was saved in AuditLog table...not the PK of the new/updated record in the Customers table.

Hopefully, that makes sense, meanwhile, I'll inspect that Metadata to see if I can find what I need.

Thanks for the help!